# Why a mutex cannot be released from an ISR

Tags: mutex, semaphore, vxworks

Vxworks states that mutual exculsion semaphores : Cannot be given inside ISR, while the condition is vaild for binary and counting semaphore.

I am not able to understand the reason out the same.

Thanks,
Zaks.

Answer (score 12):

Remember that a Mutex **must** first be acquired/taken **then** released/given.
In addition, the task that acquires the mutex **owns** it. This prevents another task from releasing a mutex it doesn't own.

With that being the case, it becomes clear that since an ISR cannot acquire a mutex (or any semaphore for that matter - it's a blocking operation), then it follows that it can't give the mutex.

It is quite possible for an ISR to do give a Binary or Counting semaphore to signal a task that something happens.  But mutexes are always a take/give pair.

To clarify a point.  In VxWorks, the ISR context is **not** the same as the context of a task!
The following scenario is invalid:

```
  Task A            ISR
  semTake(mutex)
   ....
                    semGive(mutex)
```

Task A **owns** the mutex.  When the ISR runs, it executes in a totaly different context. Most current processors have a separate ISR stack.  Since Task A owns the mutex, how could the ISR give it up?  In fact, what guarantee do you have that the ISR will fire while A has the mutex.
Even assuming you "could" give a mutex in an ISR, how would you handle the following scenario:

```
 Task A                       Task B                 ISR
  semTake(mutex)
  ...
  <context switch happens>
                              <B runs>
                                                  semGive(mutex)
```

Task A gets switched out due to a call unrelated to the mutex, and Task B runs.  The ISR now executes while B was running.  Would it still be valid for the ISR to be given?

Regardless of all this, the simple fact is that a mutex is always used in a pair of Get/Set.  I fail to see a use case where you would have an isolated semGive.

Is there a specific situation you have in mind that would require a semGive from an ISR context?

Comment: I agree with you comment that any semaphore should not be acquired in an ISR , but in case of mutex cant the same task release it which had acquired it earlier . So the statement "Mutex cannot be released within ISR" sounds a misnomer

Comment: No i donot have specific situation, I was just going through Vxworks programmers guide which states the above, didnot realise that ISR runs in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Mutexes should not be used from an interrupt because:

They include a priority inheritance mechanism which only makes sense if the mutex is given and taken from a task, not an interrupt.
**An interrupt cannot block to wait for a resource that is guarded by a mutex to become available**

https://www.freertos.org/Real-time-embedded-RTOS-mutexes.html